# Rails 3: Send E-Mail With Specific Headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to send an e-mail with specific headers. What's the way of setting all the headers in Rails 3?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the headers method inside your ActionMailer method(s) e.g.:

```
headers['X-No-Spam'] = 'True'
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#method-i-headers